# Has or could the delayed-choice quantum eraser be explained by relativity of time, the timelessness of photons moving at lightspeed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, quantum-interpretations, quantum-eraser

This question probably will or should be substantially revised...or even deleted and completely overhauled.

As far as I understood it the delayed-choice quantum eraser has always been done with photons only and with the erasing of the which-path information via the flight/detection of individual or split photons rather than irreversibly scrambling the which-path/which-form information in isolated measurement-devices/detectors after a completed/fully (non-/)detected photon-system's flight (which may warrant retrocausality-explanations).

From the point of view of observers like us, photons move at some speed (light-speed) with a past and a future. However, from the frame of reference of the photon no time passes between emission and detection/leaving the which-path information imprint even if there are possibly indeterminate decisions in-between.

Are there any explanations of the DCQE that are based on this timelessness of photons?
How valid could these be given experiments with quantum systems (i.e. electrons) that move with less than the speed of light?

Comment: I dont think there are, the results can be explained by non-relativistic quantum mechanics, so there is no need to make thing more complex that they are.

Comment: But how well and how much (plus it may make it simpler)? E.g. WP has: "the standard simplistic explanation says "The detector Di, at which the idler photon is detected, determines the probability distribution at D0 for the signal photon"" but this would require wave-function collapse via measurement, wouldn't it?

Comment: I did not remember that the explanation depended on which interpretation of QM you use, so you are correct. This adds more detail: . https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2019/09/21/the-notorious-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser/